# Mysql Inner Join Where Entry Must Match Multiple Entries

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables:

articles

```
ID    OTHER
1     foobar
2     more foobar
```

article_tags

```
ID    ARTICLE_ID    NAME
1     2             docs 
2     2             noob
3     1             docs
```

In the table above i'd like to retrieve only article id 2 because it is referenced by both docs and noob. ID 1 shouldn't be returned even though it matches docs because it does not also match noob.

I want to only retrieve an article that has both the docs and noob article_tags. I've tried using an inner join:

```
SELECT articles.* FROM articles
INNER JOIN article_tags ON article_id = articles.id
WHERE article_tags.name = 'docs' AND article_tags.name = 'noob'
GROUP BY articles.id;
```

I understand this doesn't work because the article_tag name can't be both docs and noob at the same time, but how do I go about doing this properly? Using or returns the correct article, but it also returns all articles that contain only docs or noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `JOIN` comes in handy when you want to add more columns (i.e. informations) to each row in a query.
In this case, a subquery will be better suited:

```
SELECT articles.*
FROM articles
WHERE id in (
    SELECT article_id
    FROM article_tags 
    WHERE article_tags.name IN('docs','noob')
    GROUP BY article_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) = 2
)
```

Here, the subquery will return all the *article_id*s that have both the `docs and`noob` tags, and does that by:

- selecting only the rows in the *article_tags* that have the relevant tag names
- grouping the filtered rows by *article_id* (the value we want) and keeping only the values for which there exist two or more rows*.

*: I've just noticed that if the *article_tags* has another row with *article_id*=1 and *name=*"docs", then the article "foobar" will show up in the result, which is wrong.
I think that you can fix this with a proper *PK* or an unique key on the *article_tags* table that will prevent adding another tag with the same name to the same *article_id*.
Or, probably better, by splitting up the *article_tags* table in two, creating a separate *tags* table.

Comment: Won't the OR return entries that contain only docs or only noob as well though?

Comment: That's where i'm stuck. I need to return entries that only reference multiple entries. Per my example an article must match both docs and noob. An article that references only docs or only noob should be omitted.

Comment: @ryandlf A bit of a wild guess: can you try this edited version?

Comment: @ryandlf The `>=` is because your design allows having more tags with the same name attached to the same `article_id` (unless your *PK* is preventing this)

Comment: So just to understand how this is working. The subquery is creating an array of ids that match and the primary is checking if the id is contained within that array? If I have lots and lots of docs tags for example, will the subquery pull all of those ids into the array and then loop through to look for the target?

Comment: The best way to understand how SQL queries work is to forget about arrays and such things related to programming, but to think about sets instead. Let the DBMS handle how it solves the subquery. I've added an explanation in the answer. Please be aware that my query has an issue.

Comment: @Strawberry I've tought about that, but where? I'm not selecting on *tag_name* in the inner query, and cannot select on *(article_id, tag_name)*. Well, adding another subquery perhaps...

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't knew that way to using `DISTINCT` :-)

Comment: We're all here to learn ;-). Incidentally, I disagree with your assessment about the use of subqueries.

Comment: @Strawberry Are you talking about "adding another subquery perhaps..." in one of my comments? If so, that was related to me not knowing the usage of `DISTINC` you showed me.

Comment: No. Your opening paragraph.